# Spanish words for "loop"

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, uso-de-palabras, vocabulario, definiciones

I was recently reading a review of a Spanish-English dictionary that picked "loop" as a good example of a word with many possible translations into Spanish. I looked around and found several possibilities:

- presilla
- lazo
- lazada
- curva
- meandro
- rizo
- bucle
- circuito
- círculo
- vuelta

What specifically do each of these words refer to, and what contexts would you use it in? Which is the best, generic word for "loop" (essentially, something in the shape of a circle)?

Comment: Add: ciclo ....?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- *Presilla* refers to a buttonhole made with cord.
- *Lazo* and *lazada* refers to a knot.
- *Curva* is a curve (no kidding), which can be understood as a loop depending on the context but is very rare.
- *Meandro* is each one of the corners that a river forms, as far as I know is never used to refer to a loop.
- *Rizo* and *bucle* are used to describe a loop in the hair.
- *Circuito* can be used, for example, to refeer to a racetrack or an avenue. However, its most common use is for electrical circuits.
- *Círculo* corresponds to the geometric figure (circle).
- *Vuelta* is a loop around something (like a racetrack, a block, a park, etc).
- For computational purposes, loop can be translated as *bucle* or *ciclo*.

---

However, depending on the country, all of the above words can have little variations in their meaning, my explanation refers to Mexican Spanish. For the purposes of your question, I would suggest *círculo* as the most generic word.

Comment: Good answer. I'll add that, at least in Spain, _bucle_ is used in telecom. or electrical engineering as well as computing. For example, _local loop_ would be translated as _bucle local_, and _infinite loop_ as _bucle infinito_.

Comment: Agree with MikMik, in that _bucle_ is more common than _ciclo_ for _loop_ in software (I'm from Argentina)

Comment: Gracias, chicos; editado.

Comment: En el cuarto ciclo? En la cuarta iteración? .. eso, iterar, loop.

Answer (score 3):

tambien puede significar ciclo